Relate the derivatives of two angles when given an equation of their relationship
I am working with an equation.  The equation has the following ratio between two angles:
$$\frac{d\beta}{d\phi}$$
The relationship between these two angles is
$$\tan\phi = A\tan\beta$$
I want to be able to replace the ratio of the derivative angles with something that is dependent on only one angle or neither of the angles, if possible.
Edit: Image posted of how $\beta$ and $\phi$ are visually related.  Image shows a differential section in the angled circle and the "corresponding" differential section in the projected ellipse. What I am trying to do is to relate flow of a liquid between the two differential sections, which is the equation that I mentioned as the first sentence of my post. Note that A in the equation above is equal to $\sin\theta$, which is constant.


Does $\frac{d\beta}{d\phi}$ represent the derivative of $\beta$ with respect to $\phi$? Since you talk about "ratio of the derivative angles" this sounds like you consider another differential operator.
If you really want the derivative of $\beta$ with respect to $\phi$, then you can reformulate
$\tan\phi = A\tan\beta \Leftrightarrow \beta = \arctan(\frac{1}{A}\tan\phi)$ and check then Wolfram.

Actually, in the equation, $d\beta$ is on one side and $d\phi$ is on the other side.  So it does not represent the derivative of $\beta$ with respect to $\phi$.  $\beta$ is an an angle in a circle and $\phi$ is an angle in the projection of that circle as an ellipse.  The relationship is given by the tangent equation that I posted. If the equation posted is the relationship of the angles then I guess I'm looking for the relationship of the derivates of those angles. I was trying not to complicate things, but $A=\sin\theta$ which is the angle of projection but is constant.

I don't get the difference between $d\beta$ and $\beta$ and $d\phi$ and $\phi$, Can you post an image that shows these quantities

It seems like you're interested in the derivative $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi}$, where $\beta$ and $\phi$ are related by the implicit equation
$$
\tan\phi = A\tan\beta, 
$$
where $A = \sin\theta$ is a constant $(0 \leq A \leq 1)$.
We can use implicit differentiation. Treat $\beta$ as a function of $\phi$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\phi} \bigl[ \tan\phi \bigr]
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\phi} \bigl[ A\tan\beta \bigr] \\
\sec^2\!\phi &= A \sec^2\!\beta \, \frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi},
\end{aligned}
$$
so
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi} 
= \frac{\sec^2\!\phi}{A \sec^2\!\beta}.
$$
Now, we can express this derivative explicitly in terms of either variable. For example, if we want this in terms of $\phi$, then using the Pythagorean identity
$$
\sec^2\!\beta = 1 + \tan^2\!\beta 
$$
and a bit of algebra, we get (you try it first)

 $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi} = \frac{A\sec^2\!\phi}{A^2 + \tan^2\!\phi}. $$

Here is the graph of these derivative curves for various values of $A = \sin\theta$.

You can also express this derivative in terms of $\beta$, but I leave that to you!

I'm not sure, but I don't think this is what I want.  I should have been more clear.  In the diagram that I attached, I'm looking to relate the size of the slits, which are shown as the angles $\beta$ and $\phi$.  In the material balance they are represented as $d\beta$ and $d\phi$.  So I think this would be akin to replacing $\beta$ and $\phi$ with $d\beta$ and $d\phi$ on the diagram. The equation is
$$q^2v_jd\beta = hrv_sd\phi$$
So the idea is to get $d\beta$ in terms of $d\phi$ so that I can then cancel out $d\phi$ on each side, or vice versa.

For small differences in the angles $\Delta\beta$ and $\Delta\phi$, the derivative (in its differential form, if you like) gives a good approximation, i.e.,
$$
\Delta\beta = \frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi}\Delta\phi.
$$
By a very common abuse of notation, this is just written as
$$
\mathrm{d}\beta = \frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi},\mathrm{d}\phi
= \frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2 + \tan^2!\phi},\mathrm{d}\phi.
$$
Is this what you're looking for?

Sorry, I don't understand how you came up with that equation.  From above
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\beta}{\mathrm{d}\phi}
= \frac{\sec^2!\phi}{A \sec^2!\beta}$$
But I don't understand how you made the leap from that to
$$\frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2 + \tan^2!\phi},\mathrm{d}\phi$$

There's no calculus involved in that. It's just algebraic manipulation and substitution:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sec^2!\phi}{A\sec^2!\beta}
&= \frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2\sec^2!\beta} \
&= \frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2(1 + \tan^2!\beta)} \
&= \frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2 + (A\tan\beta)^2} \
&= \frac{A\sec^2!\phi}{A^2 + \tan^2!\phi}
\end{aligned}
$$
